# Why does v-bind work differently for boolean attributes? Specifically, why does 0 evaluate as truthy?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

From the [official doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes),

```
<button v-bind:disabled="isButtonDisabled">Button</button>
```

Here, the `disabled` attribute *will* be included if `isButtonDisabled` is `0` even though in JS, `0` is considered to be a *falsy* value

Comment: From the doc `If isButtonDisabled has the value of null, undefined, or false, the disabled attribute will not even be included in the rendered <button> element.`. As `0 === false => false`, it's seems ok.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, the defined strings for not include the button is defined by the vendor and the values are not the values, Javascript converts to a falsy value, because all values are strings and not own types, like in Javascript.

From [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes):

> If `isButtonDisabled` has the value of `null`, `undefined`, or `false`, the `disabled` attribute will not even be included in the rendered `<button>` element.